# Removing old linoleum and replacing with tiles

Tags: flooring

When replacing linoleum and you pull up the old flooring some of the wood will come up. Do you replace the wood that has come up with sheet wood or wood filler then lay the tile down or should you solve it another way? I have not tried anything yet. How should I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

First you generally won't tile over plywood.  It will contract and expand too much and your tile will eventually crack.  You will need to put backerboard (size dependent on what is beneath it) over the plywood.  Generally you don't need to repair the plywood unless it is no longer flat.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert but I am in the middle of the same process so I'll share some of the knowledge I've acquired from my research on the subject.

The answer is that it completely depends upon what is underneath the linoleum.

If its particle board, your question is irrelevant because you can't lay tile on particle board (particle board expands/contracts and breaks tile/grout) unless you use a floating tile system like snapstone.  If you find particle board under the linoleum, there is a chance that it is just thin (1/4) underlayment for the linoleum and you can pull it up too.  Otherwise you need to replace the flooring.

If its plywood or OSB under the linoleum, and you are talking about gouges in the flooring from scraping the linoleum, you shouldn't have a problem as long as the floor is still level.  You will be needing to put down concrete backer board or a tiling membrane (like kerdi) over the top of your flooring anyway which will fill/address those concerns before you get to laying tile.